# Can I reset Vanity Top onto particle board with residue caulk?

Tags: caulk, vanity, particle-board

I bought a big box vanity with sink etc already attached. It was 1/4" off from being flush at the back so I decided to reseat it. Knifed and sawed the thing off then scraped the silicone off the sink/counter top.

Problem is, the wood sides are particle board and I can't get the silicone off. Nor can I cut or sand it without ruining the base. The majority of the lumpy caulk was on the sink side, so the remaining caulk on the base is fairly flat.

Is there anything I can use to simply reattach the vanity top with this residue silicone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you've set a countertop onto a vanity cabinet with silicone, then cut it loose. Some silicone remains on the top edges of the cabinet. You're asking whether you can reset the top with some silicone residue on the cabinet.

Sure.

I'd slice as much caulk off the top of the vanity as possible with a fresh utility knife blade, then set the top just as you originally did. The silicone will bond just fine. There's not much stress on it anyway.

If for some reason that doesn't work, screw some 1x2 stock to the inside of the vanity, oriented horizontally and flush on top. (There may be something in the corners already that you can use.) Run 1-1/4" drywall screws through that into the top. That's standard practice for kitchen tops, etc., where a caulk bond isn't needed.

Comment: The countertop was already set but yes, I knifed it off and cleaned the countertop. Still can't get the silicone off the particle board top edges. You had a fantastic idea with the 1x2 and I trotted off and cut the pieces. Bad news, the countertop is recessed with a beveled edge underneath.  I'd have to rip the boards with an angle so I'll just try adding silicone. Is 100 percent silicone ok?

Comment: Yes. An acrylic blend takes longer to set, doesn't bond as well, and shrinks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If using screws, make sure the countertop won't crack. ie:granite,quartz, solid surface(Corian). If particle board or soft plastic, probably ok.